# Does The Veronese map has this property

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $v_{1,2}:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^2$ be a veronese map.

I'm trying to prove that if $X$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$, then $v(X)$ is a hyperplane of the image $v(\mathbb P^1)$.

In order to solve this problem, I'm trying to prove this equality $v(Z(f))=v(\mathbb P^1)\cap Z(h)$, where $f$ is an irreducible homogeneous polynomial and $h$ is an homogeneous linear polynomial.

I'm on the right way? I need a help how to proceed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there exists necessarily a hyperplane, rather you can show that there's a hypersurface cutting $v(\mathbb{P}^1)$ in $v(X)$ by the following reason:

Veronese map on homogeneous coordinates is given by $v: [x:y] \mapsto [x^2:y^2:xy]=[X:Y:Z]$ (which is a degree $2$ map.) Let $f(x,y)$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d.$ The point is that since $f^2$ is cutting the exact variety in $\mathbb{P}^1$ i.e. $Z(f)=Z(f^2),$ then there's a homogeneous polynomial $h$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ s.t. $f^2(x,y)=h(x^2,y^2,xy)$ and any irreducible component of $Z(h)$ will do the trick.

I don't see any reason that why $h$ should have a linear part.

Comment: Why $Z(f)=z(f^2)$? why this fact implies that there is such $h$? thanks for your answer

Comment: First, simply because $f=0$ is equivalent to $f^2=0.$ Second, you can write $f^2$ as a polynomial in $x^2,y^2,xy$ call it $h.$

Comment: Dear @Ehsan, you shouldn't  take an irreducible component of $Z(h)$. The pullback of $Z(h)$ under $v $ is $Z(f^2)$, period.

Comment: Dear @Georges, you're right but $h$ may not be irreducible then!